# tput setaf color table? How to determine color codes?

Tags: bash, colors, tput

I am in the process of colorizing my terminal’s `PS1`.

I am setting color variables using `tput`; for example, here’s purple:

```
PURPLE=$(tput setaf 125)
```

#### Question:

How do I find the color codes (e.g. `125`) of other colors?

Is there a color table guide/cheat sheet somewhere?

I’m just not sure what `125` is … Is there some way to take a hex color and convert into a number that `setaf` can use?

Comment: [Updated link to the SVG colour chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg)

Answer (score 274, accepted):

The count of colors available to tput is given by `tput colors`.

To see the basic 8 colors (as used by `setf` in urxvt terminal and `setaf` in xterm terminal):

```
$ printf '\e[%sm▒' {30..37} 0; echo           ### foreground
$ printf '\e[%sm ' {40..47} 0; echo           ### background
```

And usually named as this:

```
Color       #define       Value       RGB
black     COLOR_BLACK       0     0, 0, 0
red       COLOR_RED         1     max,0,0
green     COLOR_GREEN       2     0,max,0
yellow    COLOR_YELLOW      3     max,max,0
blue      COLOR_BLUE        4     0,0,max
magenta   COLOR_MAGENTA     5     max,0,max
cyan      COLOR_CYAN        6     0,max,max
white     COLOR_WHITE       7     max,max,max
```

To see the extended 256 colors (as used by `setaf` in urxvt):

```
$ printf '\e[48;5;%dm ' {0..255}; printf '\e[0m \n'
```

If you want numbers and an ordered output:

```
#!/bin/bash
color(){
    for c; do
        printf '\e[48;5;%dm%03d' $c $c
    done
    printf '\e[0m \n'
}

IFS=$' \t\n'
color {0..15}
for ((i=0;i<6;i++)); do
    color $(seq $((i*36+16)) $((i*36+51)))
done
color {232..255}
```

[image: 256 color chart in sequence, labeled with their index]

---

The 16 million colors need quite a bit of code (some consoles can not show this).
The basics is:

```
fb=3;r=255;g=1;b=1;printf '\e[0;%s8;2;%s;%s;%sm▒▒▒ ' "$fb" "$r" "$g" "$b"
```

`fb` is `front/back` or `3/4`.

A simple test of your console capacity to present so many colors is:

```
for r in {200..255..5}; do fb=4;g=1;b=1;printf '\e[0;%s8;2;%s;%s;%sm   ' "$fb" "$r" "$g" "$b"; done; echo
```

[image: red line, fading from darker to lighter (left-to-right)]
It will present a red line with a very small change in tone from left to right. If that small change is visible, your console is capable of 16 million colors.

Each `r`, `g`, and  `b` is a value from 0 to 255 for RGB (Red,Green,Blue).

If your console type support this, this code will create a color table:

```
mode2header(){
    #### For 16 Million colors use \e[0;38;2;R;G;Bm each RGB is {0..255}
    printf '\e[mR\n' # reset the colors.
    printf '\n\e[m%59s\n' "Some samples of colors for r;g;b. Each one may be 000..255"
    printf '\e[m%59s\n'   "for the ansi option: \e[0;38;2;r;g;bm or \e[0;48;2;r;g;bm :"
}
mode2colors(){
    # foreground or background (only 3 or 4 are accepted)
    local fb="$1"
    [[ $fb != 3 ]] && fb=4
    local samples=(0 63 127 191 255)
    for         r in "${samples[@]}"; do
        for     g in "${samples[@]}"; do
            for b in "${samples[@]}"; do
                printf '\e[0;%s8;2;%s;%s;%sm%03d;%03d;%03d ' "$fb" "$r" "$g" "$b" "$r" "$g" "$b"
            done; printf '\e[m\n'
        done; printf '\e[m'
    done; printf '\e[mReset\n'
}
mode2header
mode2colors 3
mode2colors 4
```

[image: chart of sample foreground colors with their index as labels]

### [image: chart of sample background colors with their index as labels]

To convert an hex color value to a (nearest) 0-255 color index:

```
fromhex(){
    hex=${1#"#"}
    r=$(printf '0x%0.2s' "$hex")
    g=$(printf '0x%0.2s' ${hex#??})
    b=$(printf '0x%0.2s' ${hex#????})
    printf '%03d' "$(( (r<75?0:(r-35)/40)*6*6 + 
                       (g<75?0:(g-35)/40)*6   +
                       (b<75?0:(b-35)/40)     + 16 ))"
}
```

Use it as:

```
$ fromhex 00fc7b
048
$ fromhex #00fc7b
048
```

---

To find the color number as used in [HTML colors format](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp):

```
#!/bin/dash
tohex(){
    dec=$(($1%256))   ### input must be a number in range 0-255.
    if [ "$dec" -lt "16" ]; then
        bas=$(( dec%16 ))
        mul=128
        [ "$bas" -eq "7" ] && mul=192
        [ "$bas" -eq "8" ] && bas=7
        [ "$bas" -gt "8" ] && mul=255
        a="$((  (bas&1)    *mul ))"
        b="$(( ((bas&2)>>1)*mul ))" 
        c="$(( ((bas&4)>>2)*mul ))"
        printf 'dec= %3s basic= #%02x%02x%02x\n' "$dec" "$a" "$b" "$c"
    elif [ "$dec" -gt 15 ] && [ "$dec" -lt 232 ]; then
        b=$(( (dec-16)%6  )); b=$(( b==0?0: b*40 + 55 ))
        g=$(( (dec-16)/6%6)); g=$(( g==0?0: g*40 + 55 ))
        r=$(( (dec-16)/36 )); r=$(( r==0?0: r*40 + 55 ))
        printf 'dec= %3s color= #%02x%02x%02x\n' "$dec" "$r" "$g" "$b"
    else
        gray=$(( (dec-232)*10+8 ))
        printf 'dec= %3s  gray= #%02x%02x%02x\n' "$dec" "$gray" "$gray" "$gray"
    fi
}

for i in $(seq 0 255); do
    tohex ${i}
done
```

Use it as ("basic" is the first 16 colors, "color" is the main group, "gray" is the last gray colors):

```
$ tohex 125                  ### A number in range 0-255
dec= 125 color= #af005f
$ tohex 6
dec=   6 basic= #008080
$ tohex 235
dec= 235  gray= #262626
```

Comment: Lovin’ `fromhex`. Thanks again! Also, I [added a check for the `#`](https://gist.github.com/mhulse/b11e568260fb8c3aa2a8). Feedback?

Comment: Yes, removing a leading '#' is a reasonable protection. I find a lot simpler to use `hex=${1#"#"}`. It will remove nothing if `$1` does not have a `#`, and remove it if it exists. See my updated code.

Comment: Note that at least in my version of xterm the `\e[0;%s8;2;%s;%s;%sm` doesn't give me 16M colours, just the colour in the 240 colour palette that's closest to the requested rgb.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, the 16 million color do **not** work on all consoles (that is the reason for the note I added right from the start). I added now an specific test in red to "see" the (very small) change with that option. The terminal for KDE Konsole does work with 16 million color.

Comment: Of course, once "colour schemes" enter the picture, any notion of a standard palette for indexed colour, _especially_ for the 16 aixterm colours, goes completely out of the window.  As Thomas Dickey says in another answer, there _is no_ universal colour table, because it depends from the terminal emulator software _and_ from how that software happens to be configured today.

Comment: From trial and error, it seems that `48`, as in `\e[48;5;???]` a special foreground code that unlocks 256 colors and changes the meaning of `;5;` to be something other than bilnking for the background. Could someone please point to where that is documented? Ta.

Comment: Note that even though you don't need to wrap the escapes in `\[` `\]` for `printf`, you **do** need to for `PS1`.

Comment: Excellent answer, however I found odd results if passing the zero-padded number returned by fromhex() to tput.  
Compare ```echo "$(tput setaf 46)i am green"``` with ```echo "$(tput setaf 046)i am green"```
Changing the printf line to ```printf '%3d'``` fixed this.

Answer (score 38):

The [`tput` utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tput) is using a 256-color lookup table to print [8-bit ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit) (starting with <kbd>Esc</kbd> and `[`) which makes use of [terminal capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_capabilities#termcap), so these control sequences can be interpreted as colors. These are pre-defined set of 256 colors used commonly across graphic cards.

To print all 256 colors in the terminal, try the following one-liner:

```
for c in {0..255}; do tput setaf $c; tput setaf $c | cat -v; echo =$c; done
```

<sup>Hint: Append `| column` to columnate list.</sup>

This 256-color lookup table can be also found at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit) as follow:

[image: Chart; ANSI escape code; 8-bit 256-color lookup table at Wikipedia; 256-color mode — foreground: ESC[38;5;#m background: ESC[48;5;#m]

Answer (score 19):

The short answer is that you can find on the web tables of colors and match them up to the color number.

The long answer is that the correct mapping depends on the terminal —

The `125` is a parameter to an escape sequence referred to as `setaf` in the terminal description.  `tput` attaches no particular meaning to the number.  That actually depends upon the particular terminal emulator.

A while back, ANSI defined codes for 8 colors, and there were two schemes for numbering those.  The two are seen in some terminal descriptions as the pairs `setf/setb` or `setaf/setab`.  Since the latter has the connotation of "ANSI colors", you will see that used more often.  The former (setf/setb) switched the order for red/blue as noted in the ncurses FAQ *[Why are red/blue interchanged?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#interchanged_colors)*, but in either case, the scheme was established for just numbering the colors.  There is no predefined relationship between those numbers and RGB content.

For specific terminal emulators, there are predefined color palettes which can be enumerated easily enough — and can be programmed using these escape sequences.  There are **no** relevant standards, and you will see differences between terminal emulators, as noted in the xterm FAQ *[I don't like that shade of blue](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#dont_like_blue)*.

However, convention is often confused with standards.  In development of xterm over the past 20 years, it incorporated ANSI (8) colors, adapted the `aixterm` feature (16) colors, added extensions for 88- and 256-colors.  Much of that has been adopted by other developers for different terminal emulators.  That is summarized in the xterm FAQ *[Why not make "xterm" equated to "xterm-256color"?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_256color)*.

The xterm source-code includes scripts for demonstrating the colors, e.g., using the same escape sequences that `tput` would use.

You may find this question/answer helpful as well: *[RGB values of the colors in the Ansi extended colors index (17-255)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159322/rgb-values-of-the-colors-in-the-ansi-extended-colors-index-17-255)*

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Thomas, I really appreciate it! I'm on a Mac/OS X running iTerm. Your explanation really helps me understand more about my setup (I've done a lot of copy/pasting from various other people's prompt colors on the web). I really appreciate you taking the time to write me a detailed and informative reply. :)

Answer (score 15):

## ANSI Colors on console term

#### Preamble: about `$TERM` variable

Verify your environment with: `tput colors`

If you use some *compatible `xterm`* console, your `$TERM` may contain something like `xterm*`:

```
echo $TERM
xterm

tput colors
8
```

Further demos won't work: you will get image looking like:

[image]

unless you set this to `xterm-256color`:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color ; reset

tput colors
256
```

( You could even try to run this after setting `export TERM=xterm-mono` ;)

#### Doing simply the job by using `tput`

Depending on wich term protocol your console use, sequence could be: `\e[38;5;XXXm` or `\e[3XXXm` where `XXX` correspond to ansi number.

To ensure you use the right ANSI sequence, you have to use `tput`.

Regarding to [Wikipedia's ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i<256; i++)) ;do
    echo -n '  '
    tput setab $i
    tput setaf $(( ( (i>231&&i<244 ) || ( (i<17)&& (i%8<2)) ||
        (i>16&&i<232)&& ((i-16)%6 <(i<100?3:2) ) && ((i-16)%36<15) )?7:16))
    printf " C %03d " $i
    tput op
    (( ((i<16||i>231) && ((i+1)%8==0)) || ((i>16&&i<232)&& ((i-15)%6==0)) )) &&
        printf "\n" ''
done
```

Could render something like:

[image]

#### Optimizing [bash](/questions/tagged/bash): reducing forks by running `tput` as background process

... Then, because I hate runnig more than 200 forks in a little script, I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Connector fifos directory
read TMPDIR < <(mktemp -d /dev/shm/conn_shell_XXXXXXX)

fd=3
# find next free fd
nextFd() { while [ -e /dev/fd/$fd ];do ((fd++)) ;done;printf -v $1 %d $fd;}

tputConnector() {
    mkfifo $TMPDIR/tput
    nextFd TPUTIN
    eval "exec $TPUTIN> >(LANG=C exec stdbuf -o0 tput -S - >$TMPDIR/tput 2>&1)"
    nextFd TPUTOUT
    eval "exec $TPUTOUT<$TMPDIR/tput"
    rm $TMPDIR/tput
    rmdir $TMPDIR
}
myTput() { echo -e "$1\ncr" 1>&$TPUTIN && IFS= read -r -d $'\r' -u $TPUTOUT $2
}
tputConnector

myTput op op
myTput "setaf 7" grey
myTput "setaf 16" black
fore=("$black" "$grey")
for ((i=0; i<256; i++)) ;do
    myTput "setab $i" bgr
    printf "  %s%s  %3d  %s" "$bgr" "${fore[ i>231 && i<244||(i<17)&& (i%8<2)||
        (i>16&&i<232)&&((i-16)%6*11+(i-16)/6%6*14+(i-16)/36*10)<58
        ? 1 : 0 ]}" $i "$op"
    (( ((i<16||i>231) && ((i+1)%8==0)) || ((i>16&&i<232)&& ((i-15)%6==0)) )) &&
        printf "\n" ''
done
```

With only 1 fork! Same result, but approx 10x faster!

If first script run in ~1.12 second on my desk, they take upto ~47.4 seconds on my raspberry-pi!!

While second script run in ~0.11 second on my desk and ~4.97 seconds on my raspberry.

Comment: `xterm-256color` is not universally applicable, and often an incorrect choice, of course.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560992/5132

Comment: Of course, and putty is just one other implementation... I don't use putty. On my desk, I could use `gnome-terminal`, `mate-terminal`, `konsole` and `xterm` (my favorite) who all recognize *`xterm-256color`*.

Comment: No.  They are not involved in any form of "recognition", and using `xterm-256color` for them is an incorrect choice, too.  GNOME Terminal's correct terminal type is either [`gnome-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-gnome-256color) or [`vte-256colour`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-vte-256color), for example.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515517/5132

Comment: In addition to all of this, I've created a little [tag:bash] library [hsvrgb.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/hsvrgb.sh.txt), with a [hsvrgb browser](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/hsvrgb-browser.sh.txt) and a [hsvrgb demo](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/hsvrgb-demo.sh.txt).

Comment: BTW modern distribution include proper terminal definitions for putty: `find /usr/share/terminfo/ -name '*putty*' | wc -l` reports 21 on my system. And PuTTY itself sends its identity as xterm for wider compatibility, but can it send anything more appropriate if you change the default in Connection - Terminal-type string. `putty-256color` is a good start.

Comment: @nponeccop Correct, but as from one installation to other, it's a good thing to know this.

Answer (score 9):

With zsh and in an `xterm`-like terminal (`xterm` and `vte`-based terminals like `gnome-terminal`, `xfce4-terminal`... at least), you can do:

```
$ read -s -t1 -d $'\a' $'c?\e]4;125;?\a' && echo "${c##*;}"
rgb:afaf/0000/5f5f
```

The bash equivalent:

```
read -s -t1 -d $'\a' -p $'\e]4;125;?\a' c && echo "${c##*;}"
```

(you want the escape sequence to query the colour to be sent *after* the terminal discipline `echo` is disabled (with `-s`) otherwise the response would be displayed by the line discipline half of the time, hence the sending of it as part of the `read` prompt (`var?prompt` in zsh like in ksh, `-p prompt` in bash)).

to get the definition of colour 125 (here as a RGB specification, each number being the intensity of the  Red, Green and Blue components as a hex number between 0 and FFFF).

You can do the same for the first 16 colours with the `xtermcontrol` command:

```
$ xtermcontrol --get-color1
rgb:cdcd/0000/0000
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the help! +1

Comment: @Gilles, you want the query to be sent via the prompt after the terminal discipline echo is disabled. See edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Using another terminal program (gnome-terminal) (which is a xterm terminal) I got your code to work correctly (both in bash and zsh) Oddly enough: `tput colors` reports only `8` even if the terminal is capable of presenting 256 colors. Also, the xterm-color (Konsole) `tput colors` only reports `8` even if that terminal is fully capable of presenting 16 million colors (and all 256 colors, of course). And no, no tmux or screen that may "color" :-) (change that is) the results (I was aware of that detail). In short: your code may fail in some terminal/consoles.

Comment: Ah, tohex added to my answer, A bit longer than what I was expecting, but the 256 colors have quite a bit of quirk turns.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, is there how to convert XTERM colour format to ANSI colour format?

Answer (score 3):

I built on the [answer from @kenorb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438357/9745) to make the output fall into the columns that would create the gradient we are used to seeing.

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

env -i \
  TERM="$TERM" \
  LESS='--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS --chop-long-lines --no-init' \
    bash -c '
    {
      p(){
        tput setaf "$@";
        tput setaf "$@" | cat -v;
        echo ="$@";
      }
      for c in  {0..15};  do p "$c"; done | column -x -c 140;
      for c in {16..255}; do p "$c"; done | column -x -c 150;
    } | less'
```

The unnecessary semicolons are there because I developed this as a oneliner and it can easily be converted back as...

```bsh
env -i TERM="$TERM" LESS='--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS --chop-long-lines --no-init' bash -c '{ p(){ tput setaf "$@"; tput setaf "$@"|cat -v; echo ="$@"; }; for c in {0..15}; do p "$c"; done|column -x -c 140; for c in {16..255}; do p "$c"; done|column -x -c 150; }|less'
```

**NOTE:** You can copy-pasta the oneliner above as a shortcut to seeing the output of the script.

Answer (score 0):

There's the nice [`terminal-colors` Python3 script](http://zhar.net/projects/shell/terminal-colors). Here's what it gives on `xfce4-terminal`:

```bash
$ terminal-colors -n
```

[image: terminal-colors output]