# xterm: #xxxxxx into 0-255 color conversion - how?

Tags: x11, colors, xterm

I'm printing out all the 255 xterm-colors (background) using ANSI extended set background sequences, like  so: `\033[48;5;%dm` (`%d` is substituted  from 0-255). I set the xterm window color using `#eee9bf` via `.Xdefaults`  with `xrdb`:

```
XTerm*background: LemonChiffon2
```

How is it possible that the ANSI colors don't match the `#eee9bf` when I inspect visually with a little help from gimp color picker? The xterm color gamut is from 0-255 only, so what is going on here - how is xterm converting `#xxxxxx` into 0-255? How does ANSI fit into this?

```
import sys

bgn_marker = '\033[48;5;%dm '
fgn_marker = '\033[%dm'
end_marker = '\033[0m'

text = "11. hello, how are you - today is not a it;s d'ay"
space = ' ' * 40

def burp(bg):
    print '######################## %d ####################################' % bg
    for fg in range(30,38):
        print (bgn_marker + fgn_marker + text + space + end_marker) % (bg, fg)
```

(What I'm trying to do is pick a decent background for xterm that doesn't hide the ANSI colors that are often displayed when you use vim/dmesg etc.)

Answer (score 3):

ANSI has no role in this process.   It never did, except for *naming convenience*. ANSI defined a set of 8 colors which most people number 0-7.  When extending the scheme to 16-, 88- and 256-colors, it was *convenient* to make an array of color values which are addressed by the same type of index.

The X server (and your display configuration) do play a part.

xterm takes the hexadecimal value from your resources or indirectly via a name in `rgb.txt` and asks the X server for a color "close" to the R/G/B value.  The server may (and often does) approximate the colors.  In xterm's source-code, a good place to start reading is (appropriately enough) [AllocateAnsiColor](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/misc.c#L2593).

Further reading:

- [tput setaf color table? How to determine color codes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269077/tput-setaf-color-table-how-to-determine-color-codes)