# how to use 256 colors for background color in terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh, colors, gnome-terminator, ansi

I know how to use 256 colors for text in terminal:

```
printf "\033[38;5;196mhello\n"
```

But for background color, I seem to be limited to the basic 8 colors only, ie:

```
printf "\033[41mhello\n"
```

How can I use 256 colors for background colors as well ?

I mean, the terminal already know the colors, so it should be possible. But what is the syntax?

In case it is relevant, I am using `terminator` as my terminal emulator, and `zsh` as my shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `zsh`, you don't need to hardcode escape sequences as it has several builtin ways to set the background and foreground colours.

You can use `echoti setaf` to `set` the terminal `a`nsi `f`oreground colour and `echoti setab` to set the `b`ackground one (`setaf` and `setab` being the names of the corresponding `t`erm`i`nfo capabilities)

Assuming your terminal supports 256 colours (as VTE-based ones such as your gnome-terminator do) and `$TERM` is correctly set to a value that identifies a terminfo entry with the right escape sequences for that, it should work.

```
$ echoti setab 196 | sed -n l
\033[48;5;196m$
```

Or you can use prompt expansion with `print -P` or the `%` parameter expansion flag and:

```
$ print -rP '%K{196}' | sed -n l
\033[48;5;196m$
```

(here `sed -n l` is used to reveal the corresponding escape sequence that is being sent, `$` is just to show where the line ends, it's not part of the output, `\033` is GNU `sed`'s `l` command's representation of the ESC character (with octal 033 byte value in ASCII))

Some terminals (including VTE-based ones such as your gnome-terminator) also support RGB specifications. On those, you could do

```
$ print -rP '%K{#ffffff}' | sed -n l
\033[48;2;255;255;255m$
```

(here with `fffffff` for bright white as that's `ff` the maximum value for all of the red, green and blue components). In that case, `zsh` hardcodes the xterm-style sequence (see [there](https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/app/xterm/-/blob/b880aaab0d113942a4d601e315c5e62709623431/charproc.c#L1954) for the background) as there is no corresponding terminfo capability. Though not *standard*, that's currently the most widely supported across modern FLOSS terminal emulators.

`%K` sets the background colour, `%F` for foreground. `%k`/`%f` restore the default colour.

For terminals that don't  support that but do support the 88 or 256 colour palette, `zsh` also has a `zsh/nearcolor` module to get you the colour nearest to that RGB specification:

```
$ zmodload zsh/nearcolor
$ echoti colors
256
$ print -rP '%K{#ffffff}' | sed -n l
\033[48;5;231m$
```

(here colour 231 on my 256 colour terminal is the closest one to bright white, it is actually bright white).

If you have access to the X11 `rgb.txt` file, you could also define associative arrays for each of the [X11 colour names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) with something like:

```
typeset -A X11_bg X11_fg
while read -r r g b c; do
  [[ $r = [0-9]* ]] || continue
  printf -v hex %02x $r $g $b
  X11_fg[$c]=${(%):-%F{#$hex}}
  X11_bg[$c]=${(%):-%K{#$hex}}
done < /etc/X11/rgb.txt
X11_bg[default]=${(%):-%k} X11_fg[default]=${(%):-%f}
```

(Debian-like systems have `/etc/X11/rgb.txt` as part of the `x11-common` package).

To do things like:

```
print -r "$X11_bg[dark olive green]text$X11_bg[default]"
```

For more details, see:

- `man 5 terminfo`
- `info zsh echoti`
- `info zsh print`
- `info zsh "Prompt Expansion"`
- `info zsh "The zsh/nearcolor Module"`

(beware that on some systems, you need to install a `zsh-doc` package or equivalent for the `info` pages to become available).

Answer (score 6):

`printf "\033[48;5;226mhello\e[m\n"`

`printf "\033[48;2;255;255;0mhello\e[m\n"`

The more [standard variant](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Pm-m:Ps-=-4-8-colon-2-colon-Pi-colon-Pr-colon-Pg-colon-Pb.2DC1) of the second (RGB) form (which includes an unused "color space identifier" after the `2`) is not supported in older versions of the VTE library (as e.g. libvte-2.91 used by Terminator 1.91 on Debian 10).

Comment: Can you expand on this answer, please?

Comment: Would you mind editing your post to explain _why_ this solves the OPs problem?

Comment: It's sometimes better to switch back the colours with SGR 39 and SGR 49 than to reset everything with SGR 0.  And strictly speaking that version of SGR 48:2 has two mistakes, as there's properly a fifth sub-parameter.  A few terminal emulators now understand the correct T.416 form.

Comment: @JdeBP that's the only one that seems to work in the version of gnome-terminal I've tested on.

Comment: The questioner is using GNOME Terminator, notice.

Comment: @JdeBP just tried it, `printf "\033[48:2:1:255:255:0mhello\e[m\n"` does not work in Terminator 1.91. (whether with semicolons or colons)

Comment: [1.90 in 2016 claims up-to-date libvte](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/2016/11/because-theyre-like-buses-which-is.html), and that was 2 years after libvte supported this.

Comment: I don't get how the [current code](https://github.com/GNOME/vte/blob/b8a021330c0375ef6411f9abf2e4f717d0a5fb1d/src/vteseq.c#L2347) (got there following the patch link from your answer) handles any extra color space id. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the date in the corner.  Where did you get the idea that 2014 was current?  (-:  M. Koblinger [fixed the colourspace in 2017](https://github.com/GNOME/vte/commit/3c9e41211840a602a14b92eea4897ccd2704d6a4) and [even wrote about it on this WWW site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482755/is-there-a-command-to-display-colors-when-giving-hex-value-in-terminal#comment884015_482782).  So if you have 2016 GNOME Terminator, try without the sub-parameter.

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks. Please link to that patch, not to the one from 2014, which only adds support for colons and for the variant without color space.

Answer (score 2):

The direct colour and indexed colour ITU T.416 control sequences for foreground are SGR 38:2 and SGR 38:5.
The control sequences for background are similarly SGR 48:2 and SGR 48:5.

Read § 13.1.8 of ITU T.416.

```
% TERM=rxvt-256color setterm -7 --background "137" | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 34 38 3b 35 3b 31  33 37 6d                 |.[48;5;137m|
0000000b
%
```

If you ever progress beyond indexed colour, by the way, you'll need to know that there are, in fact, terminal emulators nowadays that correctly implement SGR 38:2 and SGR 48:2.
Two historical mistakes, now being rectified by some people, were not using sub-parameters and forgetting the *colour space identifier* sub-parameter.
iTerm2 fixed this back in 2013; libvte (as used in GNOME Terminator) added support for the `:` sub-parameters delimiter [in 2014](https://github.com/GNOME/vte/commit/b8a021330c0375ef6411f9abf2e4f717d0a5fb1d), and for the (ignored) color space identifier [in 2017](https://github.com/GNOME/vte/commit/3c9e41211840a602a14b92eea4897ccd2704d6a4).

```
% TERM=iterm setterm -7 --background "137" | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 34 38 3a 32 3a 3a  31 37 35 3a 31 33 35 3a  |.[48:2::175:135:|
00000010  39 35 6d                                          |95m|
00000014
%
```

## Further reading

- *[Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)*.  ECMA-48.  5th edition. 1991. ECMA International.
- *[Information technology — Open Document Architecture (ODA) and interchange format: Character content architectures](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.416/en)*.  T.416.  International Telecommunication Union.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`setterm`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/setterm.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.